# PTIJ: Where can I find a witch?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I was recently told:

> When your phone is dead, disguise yourself and visit a witch.

So I started wondering- where can I find a witch? I looked around and nobody could help me. My phone is about to die- please help! I’m looking for a witch who practices somewhere around Israel.

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: +1 for turning an absurd line fm an answer into a new PTIJ question.  Keep chaining 'em if you can, see where it goes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Talmud (Sanhedrin 67a) says that most woman are involved with which-craft.

> שרוב נשים מצויות בכשפים

If you are still doubtful weather you will indeed meet the right one, you can follow the Mishnah’s advice (Avos 2:7), and marry many woman.

> מרבה נשים מרבה כשפים

Comment: Leave it to you to find that bit of advice from *Pirkei Avot*. Very good!

Answer (score 5):

I know a good Machshefele תחי׳, actually mentioned in the Bible.

Exodus 22:17

> מכשפה-לא תחיה

Rashi says that she can be found in court.

Answer (score 2):

Like [Shaul himself](https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Samuel.28.7?lang=bi), I suggest you visit the forest-moon [Endor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endor_(Star_Wars)) to find your witch.

Answer (score 1):

There used to be a coven around Ashkelon ([Otzar Hamidrashim, Midrash Aseret Hadibrot](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Otzar_Midrashim%2C_Midrash_on_the_Ten_Commandments.1.49?vhe=Otzar_Midrashim,_New_York,_1915&lang=bi&with=Talmud&lang2=en)):

> כדתנן, ר״ש בן שטח תלה שמונים נשים מכשפות באשקלון

Translation: As we learned, Rabbi Shimon ben Shetach hanged eighty women-witches in Ashkelon.

And as we know, [nature abhors a vacuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horror_vacui_(physics)), kal v'chomer for the supernatural. So I suggest you go there, you may find the modern-day gilgul of the old coven.